# VueCompilerError: Element is missing end tag

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuejs3

i've started working with vuejs recently and i don't seem to figure out this error is shows.

[image]

And it shows the error Even though the html if fully there and there are no missing tags.

i've tried, removing comments, cleaning the file structure of the vue project.

Any help is appreciated thank you

HTML CODE, **test.vue** file :

```
<template>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
                Sidebar - Brand
                <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                        <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">John Doe</div>
                </a> </ul> </div> </template>
```

Comment: Try compiling your project again. Sometimes it doesn't detect all the changes especially the file renaming and moving.

Comment: Check for a mismatched quote.  Sometimes an odd once gets pasted in.

Comment: An `a` tag is not valid html inside a `ul` you can only put `li` inside `ul` (but I don't think it would cause the error)

Answer (score 0):

Your vue code is fine. Recompile your project. I have this issue occasionally. Recompiling always fixes it.

> Ctrl + C

> npm run serve

Answer (score -1):

I got this error while having a `vite.config.ts` that looked like this:

```
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()]
});
```

If I remove `plugins: [vue()]`, the error goes away.

Comment: Same for me any chance you figured out why this is happening?

Comment: Well of course, if you remove vue then vue won't be compiled at all